# Transforming an LDAP connection string to an Oracle ODP.NET Managed web.config <LDAPSettings />

Tags: oracle, web-config, ldap, odp.net-managed

The not-very-patient DBA in my group has given me a string similar to the following as my LDAP connection string -

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldap:/oidAAA.ourdomain.com:4444/foo,cn=OracleContext,dc=bardb
```

And according to the [Oracle Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E48297_01/doc/win.121/e41125/featConfig.htm#autoId8):

> **For OID, all ldap.ora parameters must be set with valid values to
>   complete configuration.**

I have found [a list of "all ldap.ora parameters"](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28317/ldap.htm#NETRF361) <s>but I've yet to deduce *which parts of the above connection string map to which parameters*</s>.

Thanks to some help from the DBA, I've been able to determine the following:

```
<LDAPSettings>
  <LDAPSetting name="DIRECTORY_SERVERS" value="oidAAA.ourdomain.com:4444" />
  <LDAPSetting name="DIRECTORY_SERVER_TYPE" value="OID" />
  <LDAPSetting name="DEFAULT_ADMIN_CONTEXT" value="bardb" />
</LDAPSettings>
```

The question I have now is how to actually USE this.  Assuming my database is "foo" how do I use ODP.NET to resolve this?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have enabled the config parsing

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client" type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=[...], Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=[...]"/>
[...]
```

Now you need to specify your connection string

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="myFooConnection" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" connectionString="User Id=[...];Password=[...];Data Source=foo"/>
```

Note the `Data Source=foo` part. It uses the configured TNS, LDAP etc. to resolve the connection.

You can reference the connection by name `myFooConnection` with compatible ASP.Net controls or directly pass the connection string to an `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection`

VB.Net:

```
Dim connectionString As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("myFooConnection").ConnectionString
Dim connection As New Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection(connectionString)
```